# O valor dos gráficos só aparece quando a resolução da página é alterada

Tags: javascript

Tenho 2 gráficos em JavaScript que estão a receber valores através de um ficheiro PHP. No entanto esses valores só aparecem no gráfico quando a resolução da página web por algum motivo é alterada.
Este é o código de JavaScript que tenho:

```js
demo = { 
  initDashboardPageCharts: function() {
    var dataSales = {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
      series: []
    };

    var optionsSales = {
      lineSmooth: false,
      low: 0,
      high: 100,
      showArea: true,
      height: "245px",
      axisX: {
        showGrid: false,
      },
      lineSmooth: Chartist.Interpolation.simple({
        divisor: 3
      }),
      showLine: false,
      showPoint: false,
      fullWidth: false
    };

    var responsiveSales = [
      ['screen and (max-width: 640px)', {
        axisX: {
          labelInterpolationFnc: function(value) {
            return value[0];
          }
        }
      }]
    ];

    var chartHours = Chartist.Line('#chartHours', dataSales, optionsSales, responsiveSales);
  }
}
```

Se quiserem ver por vocês mesmos, podem ver [aqui](http://www.iot.dei.estg.ipleiria.pt/ti/eid-pl06-g07/projetoEx/index.php).
Como posso resolver isto para os valores aparecerem sempre ?

Answer (score 0):

Após:

```
var chartHours = Chartist.Line('#chartHours', dataSales, optionsSales, responsiveSales);
```

Adicione:

```
setTimeout(function() { chartHours.update(); }, 0);
```

Problema relacionado: 
https://github.com/willsoto/angular-chartist.js/issues/22

Comment: Não resolveu o problema :v